# How to change html encoded character to ascii character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, utf-8

I have a french character that is encoded as follows:

"Jos\xE9e"

I need to convert it to regular character because it produces this error on my server:

invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

What can I do to fix this error?

Rails 3 Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like "Josée" encoded in [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) (AKA Latin-1). You can use [Iconv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/Iconv.html) to convert it to UTF-8:

```
require 'iconv'
utf_string = Iconv.conv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', "Jos\xE9e")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a editor support utf-8, and add coding line at the top of all source files:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

If some input string is not utf-8, convert it to utf-8 first before processing:

```
input_str = "Jos\xE9e"
utf_input = input_str.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

All above only work under ruby 1.9. For more information, you can check the book: Ruby Best Practices.

Answer (score 0):

you should use utf8 in all your source code, how about save your file in utf-8 encoding